# How to get the previous and next object from the current object in Angular?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently building my portfolio with Angular. I have **2 controllers** and **2 views/templates**: one that displays the list of my projects, and one that displays the individual project.

```
.controller('ProjectListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data/projects.json').success(function(projectsRef){
        $scope.projects = projectsRef;
        $scope.getSlug = function(text){
            return text.replace(/\W+/g, '-');
        };
    });
}])

.controller('ProjectDetailController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', '$sce', function($scope, $http, $routeParams, $sce){
    $http.get('data/projects.json').success(function(projectsRef){
        $scope.project = projectsRef[$routeParams.id];

        $scope.project = _.find(projectsRef, function(project) {
          return project.title.replace(/\W+/g, '-') === $routeParams.id;
        });
    });
}])
```

This is how I get to each project individually

`<a class="btn-default" href="#/portfolio/{{getSlug(project.title)}}">View Project</a>`

**projects.json**

```
 {
   "001" : {
    "keywords" : "Web Design, HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Responsive, Wordpress",
    "title" : "Primetime Learning Centers",
    "brief" : "content",
    "featured" : "img/screenshots/primetime.jpg",
    "shots" : [
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/primetime1.jpg"}, 
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/primetime2.jpg"}, 
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/primetime3.jpg"}
     ]
  },

  "002" : {
    "brief" : "content",
    "keywords" : "Web Design, HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Responsive, Drupal",
    "title" : "HIV Stops With me",
    "featured" : "img/screenshots/hswm.jpg",
    "shots" : [
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/hswm5.jpg"},
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/hswm6.jpg"},
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/hswm7.jpg"}
    ]
  },
  "003" : {
    "brief" : "content",
    "keywords" : "HTML5, CSS3, jQuery, Responsive, Drupal",
    "title" : "LGBT China",
    "featured" : "img/screenshots/lgbt-china.jpg",
    "shots" : [
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/china1.jpg"}, 
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/china2.jpg"}, 
      {"url" : "img/screenshots/china3.jpg"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Ive been trying to add a button that says Next and Previous on the individual project pages that goes to the previous and next object.
I tried using $index and id but couldn't figure it out. Any ideas how I can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say, $index works well in array, but your json seems a object, maybe you should try change it to array structure..

Comment: Is it not possible to do it with an object?

Comment: I am not sure, just I used it a lot, all array, for example, [{....}, {...}, ]

Comment: Well, I need them as objects.. so i ended up just creating a 'next' and 'previous' properties to each